Как подружить фаерволлы в Symfony
В моем файле security.yaml определены два фаерволла, оба работают с конечными точками api. Однако они проверяют разные способы аутентификации: один для сервисных приложений через api_key, другой - для пользователей через jwt токен. Как сделать так чтобы они работали по принципу: если не сработал один фаерволл, то будет проверяться другой?
firewalls:
        service:
            pattern: ^/api/v1
            provider: app_application_provider
            stateless: true
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\AppAuthentificator
        api:
            pattern: ^/api/v1
            provider: app_user_provider
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~


Вероятно, надо создать собственный кастомный фаервол и использовать его. Внутри него соответственно будут уже фаерволы поменьше)
